# How to fix `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function send() on null` after removing composer package in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Here's the error anytime, I try to open root

```
  WARN  PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function send() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Atlas\club\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php:222.  
   WARN  Stack trace:  
   WARN  #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Atlas\club\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(199): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse(Object(Error)).
   WARN  #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Atlas\club\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(259): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Error)).
   WARN  #2 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}(Object(Error)).
   WARN  #3 {main}.
   WARN  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Atlas\club\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php on line 222.
   WARN  PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function send() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Atlas\club\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php:222.
   WARN  Stack trace:
   WARN  #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Atlas\club\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(199): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError)).
   WARN  #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Atlas\club\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(235): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError)).
   WARN  #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Atlas\club\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(259): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown().  
   WARN  #3 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}().
   WARN  #4 {main}.
   WARN  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Atlas\club\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php on line 222.
```

Here's what I've tried for removing package and fixing the issue :

- I've had `Laravel Modules` package installed.
- Removed package using `Composer remove nWidart/laravel-modules`
- Removed config file
- Removed cached files
- Removed `composer.lock` file
- Updated `composer.json` file to remove `Autoload` line due to requirement to use modules. (Note, I didn't removed whole `Autoload` block, only one `Module\\`'s line.)
- `Composer update`
- `Composer dumpautoload` And `composer dump -o
- Removed `vendor` directory
- Tried revert changes with git. (Was trying to see if I've done anything to composer by mistake or etc.)
- There's no reference to Laravel modules package in application and same error is stored in `laravel.log`

Basic Project info :

- Laravel : ^9.2
- PHP : 8.1.4

Comment: where You're calling `->send()` ? if You know please add that code to question

Comment: @num8er I'm not using `send()` at all, nothing changed in my code. I've installed the package, then had some issues with vite and I removed it. That's all. not a single code included or removed.

Comment: @num8er Also error is clearly mentioning where, `send` is used and getting called.

Comment: send is being called when it tries to do response->send to handle exception page to be sent. seems like response object in bootstrap file is null. to understand it need to debug or enable on php configs `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @num8er, right now It's fixed. I've created another blade and copy everything from old to new, exact file, and there was no warning again. I'm still trying to figure out what happening, since I'm not new to Laravel and It was so wierd..., thanks.

Comment: I suspect if You'll have exceptions again it will show same error, since some package is returning null as response object. Just simply try to add root action `throw \Exception('testing');`  if it will show proper error page then it means You somehow deleted default error pages previously.

Comment: @num8er, I've tried that before, nothing changed, simply problems fixed by re-creating the blade and moving everything from old to new, and sound so stupid... everything work now. thanks again.